# Why OffsetX of TranslateTransform3D can't be modified after DoubleAnimation?

Tags: wpf, transform

My code is here, and I can't edit the offset property of `TranslateTransform3D` any more after running this:

```
                DoubleAnimation doubleAnimationX =
                    new DoubleAnimation(x,
                                        new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second)));
                DoubleAnimation doubleAnimationY =
                    new DoubleAnimation(y,
                                        new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second)));
                DoubleAnimation doubleAnimationZ =
                    new DoubleAnimation(z,
                                        new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second)));
                                                     translate.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetXProperty, doubleAnimationX);
                                                     translate.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetYProperty, doubleAnimationY);
                                                     translate.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetZProperty, doubleAnimationZ);
```

Answer (score 1):

TranslateTransform3D derives from [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx).  Your translate is being frozen after the animation, which makes it immutable.